# How can I get this function to be tail-recursive?

Tags: recursion, f#, stack-overflow, tail-recursion, continuations

I'm [still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854211/) trying to implement 2-3 finger trees and I made good progress ([repository](https://github.com/CmdQ/23-finger-tree/blob/master/FingerTree/FingerTree.fs)). While doing some benchmarks I found out that my quite basic `toList` results in a `StackOverflowException` when the tree ist quite large. At first I saw an easy fix and made it tail-recursive.

Unfortunately, it turned out that `toList` wasn't the culprit but `viewr` was:

```
/// Return both the right-most element and the remaining tree (lazily).
let rec viewr<'a> : FingerTree<'a> -> View<'a> = function
    | Empty -> Nil
    | Single x -> View(x, lazyval Empty)
    | Deep(prefix, deeper, One x) ->
        let rest = lazy (
            match viewr deeper.Value with
            | Nil ->
                prefix |> Digit.promote
            | View (node, lazyRest) ->
                let suffix = node |> Node.toList |> Digit.ofList
                Deep(prefix, lazyRest, suffix)
        )
        View(x, rest)
    | Deep(prefix, deeper, Digit.SplitLast(shorter, x)) ->
        View(x, lazy Deep(prefix, deeper, shorter))
    | _ -> failwith Messages.patternMatchImpossible
```

Looking for the only recursive call it is obvious that this is is not tail-recursive. Somehow I hoped this problem wouldn't exist because that call is wrapped in a `Lazy` which IMHO is similar to a continuation.

I heard and read of continuations but so far never (had to) use(d) them. I guess here I really need to. I've been staring at the code for quite some time, putting function parameters here and there, calling them other places… **I'm totally lost!**

How can this be done?

---

**Update:** The calling code looks like this:

```
/// Convert a tree to a list (left to right).
let toList tree =
    let rec toList acc tree =
        match viewr tree with
        | Nil -> acc
        | View(head, Lazy tail) -> tail |> toList (head::acc)
    toList [] tree
```

---

**Update 2:** The code that caused the crash is this one.

```
let tree = seq {1..200000} |> ConcatDeque.ofSeq
let back = tree |> ConcatDeque.toList
```

The tree get built fine, I checked and it is only 12 levels deep. It's the call in line 2 that triggered the overflow.

---

**Update 3:** [kvb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82959/kvb) was right, that [pipe issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722526/) I ran into before has something to do with this. Re-testing the cross product of debug/release and with/without pipe it worked in all but one case: debug mode with the pipe operator crashed. The behavior was the same for 32 vs. 64 bit.

I'm quite sure that I was running release mode when posting the question but today it's working. Maybe there was some other factor… Sorry about that.

---

Although the crash is solved, I'm leaving the question open out of theoretical interest. After all, we're here to learn, aren't we?

So let me adapt the question:
**From looking at the code, `viewr` is definitely not tail-recursive. Why doesn't it always blow up and how would one rewrite it using continuations?**

Comment: Does this help? http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/12/22/tail-recurse

Comment: The laziness does mean that there's effectively no recursive call at all - the problem is the interaction between this function and its caller(s).  Could you also provide the calling code?

Comment: @kvb: Done. In case you need to see more, the whole repo is linked at the beginning.

Comment: Could you also include an argument that causes the exception?  And what's your runtime environment?

Comment: In F# Interactive (x64) on Windows, I'm able to call `toList` as is on a tree with 1M elements without getting a stack overflow.

Comment: Another update. For the exact settings on that machine, I'd have to get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: That code also works for me in my environment.

Comment: Perhaps you're hitting the same issue as you did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722526/can-does-the-forward-pipe-operator-prevent-tail-call-optimization)?  Try removing the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `viewr` never results in an immediate recursive call to `viewr` (the recursive call is protected by `lazy` and is not forced within the remainder of the call to `viewr`), so there's no need to make it tail recursive to prevent the stack from growing without bound.  That is, a call to `viewr` creates a new stack frame which is then immediately popped when `viewr`'s work is done; the caller can then force the lazy value resulting in a new stack frame for the nested `viewr` call, which is then immediately popped again, etc., so repeating this process doesn't result in a stack overflow.